# Not getting host, id, channel number of scsi

Tags: linux, ioctl, scsi, pci-bus

I am writing a program which will print host, channel number, id number, lun of a SCSI device.

```
cat /proc/scsi/scsi
```

giving the information about it. But i want print it through c program. I'm getting vendor id, device type, revision level... but not lun , bus no etc.

Is there any `ioctl` command to get lun, bus,  id numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try the ioctls for SCSI generic :

http://sg.danny.cz/sg/p/sg_v3_ho.html#ioctl ?

SCSI_IOCTL_GET_IDLUN, SG_GET_SCSI_ID should do the trick.

I did not use any SCSI HW in the last years though, and I hope the documentation is still valid for current kernels. I don't see any reason to have changed the ioctls though.